# Unreadable Firebase ML Kit Text Recognition Project

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I made a license plate scan application with the vehicle, for coding it will run smoothly and there are no errors, but when scanning the vehicle plate the plate number doesn't want to appear, for the project using Firebase ML Kit Text Recognition

https://github.com/AdityaWiradarma/aplikasi-scan-plat-nomor.git

[image: application image]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is deprecated by MLKit, gave you tried the MLKit sample app?
Check https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart and https://developers.google.com/ml-kit. You can try the image above with the sample app.